# while select deselect row on didselectrow at indexPath getting crash

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am creating My first `Swift` app and i am populating `JOSN` data into `UITableview` and with `struct` model let me show you my code of populating `JSON` data

**Here Is My Struct Model**

```
struct QuotationListModel{
    var id: String
    var quantity: String
    var margin: String
    var created_date: String
    var part_number: String
    var total_price: String
    var freight: String
    var fk_customer_id: String
}
```

And In My `ViewController` i have delared Array like below

```
var quotationData = [QuotationListModel]()
var arrSelectedIds = [String]()
```

below is my API Calling Function

```
func quotationListAPI(){
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!]
    print(params)
    self.viewMainSpinner.isHidden = false
    self.viewInnerSpinner.startAnimating()
    Alamofire.request(quatationlist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let data = json["quation_list"]
            print(data)
            if data == []{
                self.viewMainSpinner.isHidden = true
                self.viewInnerSpinner.stopAnimating()
            }else{
                data.array?.forEach({ (qList) in
                    let q_list = QuotationListModel(id: qList["id"].stringValue, quantity: qList["quantity"].stringValue, margin: qList["margin"].stringValue, created_date: qList["created_date"].stringValue, part_number: qList["part_number"].stringValue, total_price: qList["total_price"].stringValue, freight: qList["freight"].stringValue, fk_customer_id: qList["fk_customer_id"].stringValue)
                    self.quotationData.append(q_list)
                })
                self.tblListView.reloadData()
                self.viewMainSpinner.isHidden = true
                self.viewInnerSpinner.stopAnimating()
            }
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.viewMainSpinner.isHidden = true
            self.viewInnerSpinner.stopAnimating()
        }

    })
}
```

So with this array i am populating data from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` till now every things work perfect for me

but on didselect when i deselect the row with is already selected then i am getting crash here is my code for `didSelect`

But now i want select all rows of all tableview on Select All button click  so for that i have used below code and its work fine for me here is my code

```
@IBAction func btnSelectAllTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if btnSelectAll.titleLabel?.text == "Select All"{
        self.btnSelectAll.setTitle("DeSelect All", for: .normal)
        self.btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 119/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = false
        self.arrSelectedIds = quotationSeelctedData.map({ (quotation: QuotationListModel) -> String in quotation.id })
        print(arrSelectedIds)
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }else{
        self.isSelectAll = false
        btnSelectAll.setTitle("Select All", for: .normal)
        btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = true
        self.arrSelectedIds.removeAll()
        print(arrSelectedIds)
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is my code for `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! QuotationTableViewCell
    let id = quotationSeelctedData[indexPath.row].id
    if self.arrSelectedIds.contains(id){
        cell.viewMain.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 251/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.imgView.isHidden = false
    }else{
        cell.viewMain.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.imgView.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.lblPartNumber.text = quotationData[indexPath.row].part_number
    cell.llbQuantity.text = quotationData[indexPath.row].quantity
    cell.lblFreight.text = quotationData[indexPath.row].freight
    cell.lblMargin.text = quotationData[indexPath.row].margin
    cell.lblTotal.text = quotationData[indexPath.row].total_price
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

so select all functionality works perfect for me

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    let id = quotationSeelctedData[indexPath.row].id
    print(id)
    if arrSelectedIds.contains(id){
        self.arrSelectedIds.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print(self.arrSelectedIds)
        if self.arrSelectedIds.count == 0{
            btnSelectAll.setTitle("Select All", for: .normal)
            btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
            self.btnShare.isHidden = true
        }
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }else{
        self.arrSelectedIds.append(id)
        print(self.arrSelectedIds)
        self.btnSelectAll.setTitle("DeSelect All", for: .normal)
        self.btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 119/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = false
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

so please can any one help me for solving this thanks in advance

Comment: Post error what you getting on crash.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are using an extra array for the selected ids rather than adding a `isSelected` member to the struct

The index path is not necessarily the index of the item as an id  is just appended to the array

Replace

```
if arrSelectedIds.contains(id){
    self.arrSelectedIds.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

With

```
if let index = arrSelectedIds.index(of: id){
    self.arrSelectedIds.remove(at: index)
```

Nevertheless delete `arrSelectedIds` and add a member `isSelected` to the struct.

Comment: i have one more confusion can you help me to solve it out

Comment: Please ask a new question and insert only the relevant code

Comment: thats not hard question i just want to i want store all selected data in to array so how can i set all selected data into array

Comment: Actually it's a hard question with your design. If you follow my suggestion to put the `selected` information in the struct you can simply `filter` the array (`.filter{$0.isSelected}`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886054/store-tableview-selected-data-into-array-with-key-value pelase check i have asked new question