# store tableview selected data into array with key value

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding

i am new to swift and and i have created tableview select all rows functionality so select deselect works fine for me but now i want data which is selected in tableview so i tried to create struct model with `Encodable` like below

```
class QuotationListDataModel: Encodable{
    var id: String?
    var quantity: String?
    var margin: String?
    var created_date: String?
    var part_number: String?
    var total_price: String?
    var freight: String?
    var fk_customer_id: String?

    init(id: String?,quantity: String?,margin: String?,created_date: String?,part_number: String,total_price: String,freight: String,fk_customer_id: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.margin = margin
        self.created_date = created_date
        self.part_number = part_number
        self.total_price = total_price
        self.freight = freight
        self.fk_customer_id = fk_customer_id
    }
}
```

and i want out put like below

```
[
  {
   margin: 20,
   quantity: 10
   part_number: 15
   total_price: 1500
   freight: 100
  },
  {
   margin: 20,
   quantity: 10
   part_number: 15
   total_price: 1500
   freight: 100
  }
]


@IBAction func btnSelectAllTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if btnSelectAll.titleLabel?.text == "Select All"{
        self.btnSelectAll.setTitle("DeSelect All", for: .normal)
        self.btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 119/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = false
        self.arrSelectedIds = quotationSeelctedData.map({ (quotation: QuotationListDataModel) -> String in quotation.id! }) 
         //Here when user select all i want all data into array
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }else{
        self.isSelectAll = false
        btnSelectAll.setTitle("Select All", for: .normal)
        btnSelectAll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
        self.btnShare.isHidden = true
        self.arrSelectedIds.removeAll()
        print(arrSelectedIds)
        self.tblListView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

so i want selected data like this can anyone please help me to solve it out

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, do you want to encode your array of selected rows to json, is that it?

Comment: yes i want to encode selected data

Comment: @Green, Your question and your comment are different. What you want? **1. do you want selected row object data?** or **2. do you want to encode selected data?**

Comment: i want to encode selected data

Answer (score 0):

you could create an array like
`var  QuotationList = [QuotationListDataModel]()`
in didSelect delegate you could add the model to your list like

```
QuotationList = allDataArray[indexPath.row]
```

selected data will be added to your array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(MYARRAY)
    if let jsonString = String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        // That's your JSON string...
        print(jsonString)
    }
} catch {
    print("the encoding failed")
}
```

Anyway you need to fetch your items by ID... a better and faster solution would be to use the indexpath of the selected cells and extract them from your datasource.

EDIT: as stated by Joakim Danielson, add the desired CodingKeys.

Answer (score 0):

To encode your rows you need to add an enum containing the properties you want to be part of the encoded data to your class

```
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case margin, quantity, part_number, total_price, freight
  }
```

Then you can encode it like this

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(arr)                                 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Some questions to consider, why are all properties of type String and why are all optional?